# CentOS 5.8 Change Cursor Size in XDM

Tags: cursor, centos

Looking to change the size of the cursor in CentOS 5.8 XDM.
We have changed the cursor file in /usr/share/X11/fonts/misc/cursor.pcf.gz to no avail. We have also tried using xcursorgen with a PNG and .cursor config file, again to no avail. 
Perhaps there is a way in which we can point the system to our new big black cursor that we have created?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the contents of an existing theme into `/usr/share/icons/default` and that will be picked up when the X-server is restarted. This will keep the cursor theme when using the MWM theme. I'm not sure about other themes.